# WPF trigger template on every button

Tags: button, triggers, wpf-4.0

I have created a Button with the following trigger:

```
                    <Button Content="Test>
                      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SetViewModelToOpen">
                                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadButton}},Path=Content}" />
                            </cal:ActionMessage>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```

Now I have several button like this one and want this trigger to be applied to every button. 
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use styles, in your case:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonWithTriggers" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <[Place your actions here]>
        </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then your button declaration:

```
<Button Content="Test" Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithTriggers}" />
```